# How to pass 'yes' in a Python command inside a tmux session

Tags: python, python-3.x, tmux

I have the following bash script, which runs a Python script in the `tmux` session. The script prompts for two `y/n` responses.

```
#!/bin/sh 
tmux new-session -d -s new_session 'python3 build.py /data/build/'
```

Tried the following code to pass 'y' everytime, but it didn't work when executed in the tmux session.

```
python3 build.py -y /data/build/
```

How can the same be done in tmux?

Comment: Are you sure `build.py` *takes* a `--y` option? I don't see how `tmux` would affect your script's argument handling.

Comment: my bad, it was a typo.  I tried with -y

Comment: Same question: `-y` is not a universal convention to signal that a given string should be repeated on standard input.

Comment: You can use the `yes` command  instead, assuming that `build.py` does read from standard input and not directly from the terminal. `yes | python build.py /data/build`

Comment: Yes, it works. I tried the same, but with echo.
Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

To run 'yes' by default, use this-

```
yes | python3 build.py /data/build/
```

answered by @[chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner)

Comment: That only sends a *single* line `yes` to your script. The `yes` program will output an infinite stream of "yes"es, so that your script can read as many lines as necessary to answer all prompts. (When the script exits, `yes` will exit as well when it tries to write to the now-closed pipe.)

Comment: Yes, @chepner, you are right. I have updated the answer